# Reverse execution support when using real network

Tags: simics

I'm aware reverse execution doesn't work in configuration using real network.
Are there plans to make it working ?
Reverse execution would be very useful in debugging network code that is stochastic by definition when it comes to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse execution requires deterministic behavior, as you said by other words. No, we are not going to change that. Actually, in version 7 reverse execution has been removed in favor of "in-memory snapshots".

Back to the question, for debugging network code you could try running two separate machines in the same Intel® Simics® simulator session, and send traffic from one machine to the one with the code you want to debug. You can also use `pcapdump` to save network traffic, inspect it, and replay it. There is some information in the *Ethernet Networking Technology Guide*.

#IAmIntel // Simon

Comment: Just a clarification: with "in memory snapshots" is it possible to debug a replayed execution staring before or after the bookmark ?